# Restrict registers showed to users in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I have a table in the Web->List and I need that the users only see the registers that they own, not the totality of them.

Do you know how to do this? Is there a hook or typoscript to modify the query?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you want to do? Your Backend Users should only see a few frontend users? Or do you talk about Frontend? What means Web->List then. Tell us, what do you want to archive.

Comment: Hi @maholtz, I have registers of different tables in TYPO3, that are displayed under the Web->List menu. (For the case suppose the registers are client tickets). And the situation is that each ticket is linked with an employee, but when the employee see the list, all the tickets are displayed and I want that only the tickets linked with the user be displayed. ¿Is it clear? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Create a view in the frontend for your employees. IMHO it makes no sense to try to do it in the backend.